# Inserting a new attribute in to a column of a table calculated from difference in minute between two column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Need Help with the following question:

Run Monash has decided that they would like to have the elapsed time (finish time - start time)
for a runner in a particular event stored as part of the system, rather than having to calculate it
every time it is required.
Add a new attribute which will record the runners elapsed time in an event. The time should be
stored as the number of minutes elapsed to two decimal places eg. 26.12
This attribute must be initialised to the correct elapsed time based on the data which is currently
stored in the system. You should note that the system may contain registrations for future events
which currently do not have either a start or finish time.

An example of what's inserted into the entry table is

```
INSERT INTO entry(entrystarttime,entryfinishtime) 
VALUES (TO_DATE('01-feb-2018:10:00:00 AM', 'dd-mon-yyyy:hh:mi:ss am'),
    TO_DATE('01-feb-2018:10:59:30 AM', 'dd-mon-yyyy:hh:mi:ss am');
```

Both columns' datatype is date so the table looks something like this

```
ENTRYSTARTTIME  ENTRYFINISHTIME
--------------  ---------------
01/FEB/2018     01/FEB/2018
```

This is what i attempted to add a new attribute to the table called entryelapsedtime

```
alter table entry add (entryelapsedtime number(7,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL);
UPDATE entry
SET
  entryelapsedtime = (entryfinishtime - entrystarttime) * 24 * 60, 2
SELECT * from entry;
```

However this doesn't work, therefore i need help writing this modification 
so i get a table that looks like this:

```
ENTRYSTARTTIME  ENTRYFINISHTIME  ENTRYELAPSEDTIME
--------------  ---------------  --------------
01/FEB/2018      01/FEB/2018        59.5
```

Comment: "this doesn't work" because on the right-hand side you meant to wrap everything within `ROUND(....)`  -  you even have the  ` , 2` there but **ROUND(  )** itself is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work?

```
UPDATE entry
    SET entryelapsedtime = (entryfinishtime - entrystarttime) * 24 * 60;
```

I'm not sure what the `, 2` is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Hi thank you i thought i need the , 2 for 2 decimal place ,but turns out it already is. It now works.

Comment: @Fish - it works (including the rounding) because you declared your column as having only two decimal places. So Oracle does the rounding explicitly, even if you don't round in the formula yourself. It is always best to do things explicitly in your code and not rely on implicit actions; do use ROUND(.... , 2) in the INSERT.